# How to solve the case when revealViewController is equal to nil after I leave ViewController and return?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I have used SWReavealController to implement a side bar menu. However when I leave my view controller move to another and return it no longer works. This only happens after specific segues.

Code to initialise the burger menu:

```
func initBurgerMenu(){
    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButtonRight.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButtonRight.action = "rightRevealToggle:"
    }
}
```

Comment: your front view controller must be associated with the  navigation controller ..and thus pushing view controller from there wont make nil revealViewController

Comment: @anishparajuli It is already associated with a navigation controller, however the second view isn't - could that be the issue?